# Excluding simple log statements from jacoco coverage report

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

Some of methods in our app are more informative which majorly logs state of a particular component at a given time or informative to report an event, ex following code:

```
    @Override
    public void close() {
        logger.info("Stopping Component...");
    }
```

Since there is no point of writing test cases agains such methods, is their any way by which we can define to ignore logger from jacoco coverage reports to increase code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FilteringOptions](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/FilteringOptions) were added in version 0.8.0, released January 3rd, 2018.

Comment: Great link - made it easy to me to check the docs and see that this was in fact implemented back in January 2018. I scrapped the rest of the original answer.